# SSRS Conditional Expression, Change Background Color

Tags: dictionary, reporting-services, conditional-statements

Working with a map in SSRS and I need a conditional statement that will change the background color for the three counties with the highest client count.

Keep in mind that these totals vary across 39 counties, 10 different races and date span of 12 months. The values fluctuate from one race to another.  For example, Hispanic Native Americans = 350 for the entire state compared to White's total over 1,000,000 across the state.

Thanks

Comment: what you have tried so far? did you search for condition expression to change background color?

Comment: Yes, however all the expressions use a constant like : =IIF(Fields!Race.Value <= 100000, "Red", "#8c90cc") .... I need a conditional statement that highlights the 3 highest populated counties.  Lets' s say King County has 20 Hispanic Native Americans , Pierce has 19 and Thurston has 18 and those are the 3 highest counties for that population...they would be red..If the user selected White, King County has 400,000 , Pierce has 300,000 and Thurston has 200,000 and those are the 3 highest counties for that population..they would be red.

Comment: Currently, the map works perfectly.  The user can select a month/year and a race and see the populations for those attributes across the state...now they want the 3 highest populated counties to stand out.

Comment: My problem is that the totals vary so dramatically across race groups, that I can't hard code a value like <=100000 because it won't work for the smaller populations